# What are the principal differences on siddhanta basics, and details, between tradional vedantists and neo-vedantists?

Tags: vedanta, neo-vedanta

Although my personal experience has been limited to observing some rather intense debates between traditional advaitins and neo-advaitins, this differentiation seems to have been extended to vedantists in general and by further extension, to hinduism itself. So, it would be good to understand the differences at the different levels.

Comment: Caste gender etc. Neo vedanta is more open and less orthodox

Comment: Great question! I want to see the answers. I have seen twitter fights labelling each others as neo and fanatic orthodox.

Comment: @RaRa Twitter is hardly a proper "forum" for these kind of discussions. I have been an observer on this forum though for quite sometime and decided that it would good to engage with. I think fanatics exist on both sides... I myself am fanatic on certain things. Who would not be when it comes to substantiated beliefs? :D

Comment: @Ambi I have never engaged with anything on twitter. I observed for a few days and deactivated my account. This is a much better forum where people are decent.

Comment: what is neo-vedanta ?

Comment: @ram bit like more modern, unorthodox.. follows a diluted version as orthodox would call. Adaptable and flexible version as neo themselves would describe. But let's wait for an expert answer to distinguish between both.

Comment: @RaRa, you mean somebody concocted their own version ? does it have any sanction by shastras ?

Comment: Neo-Vedanta needs to be defned before this queestion can be answered. Vivekananda and Radhakrishnan have been both called neo-Vedantist. The term Neo-Vedanta meant one thing to late 19th-early 20th century Bengal. It means another to western Indoogists. So which Neo-Vedanta are you talking about?

Comment: @ram both can justify from scriptures quoting some portions.. other party says that is an exception and rare.. Neo says this is more suitable now. Lets wait for answer. But I don't know whats in the mind of OP when he used neo vedanta term.

Comment: OK. I didn't certainly mean to start a discussion on WHAT Neo vedanta or hinduism is. There are certainly many variations to it, but my understanding is they don't have much to differ among themselves. This might be wrong and I am willing to correct my understanding. But for simplicity sake, let's consider the neo variant to be one that has been popularized by western scholars AND/OR the version of hinduism/vedanta that has been specifically catering to a western crowd.

Comment: [This introduction](http://www.advaita.org.uk/discourses/trad_neo/neo_vedanta_swartz.htm) to Neo-Vedanta and [Comparison](http://www.advaita.org.uk/discourses/trad_neo/trad_neo.htm) with traditional Vedanta may be useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Western Indologists consider Rammohun Roy, Keshab Chandra Sen, Ramakrishna, Vivekananda and Radhakrishnan as exponents of different varieties of Neo Vedanta. I will only discuss the views of Ramakrishna, Vivekananda on some issues and to a smaller extent Radhakrishnan.

**Ramakrishna and Vivekananda**

**Vedas are not proof**. Anubhav or aparokshanubhuti obtained through sadhana is the proof.

> "There are certain religious facts which, as in external science, have
>   to be perceived and upon them religion will be built. Of course, the
>   extreme claim that you must believe every dogma of a religion is
>   degrading to the human mind. The man who asks you to believe
>   everything, degrades himself, and, if you believe, degrades you too.
>   The sages of the world have only the right to tell us that they have
>   analyzed their minds and have found these facts, and if we do the same
>   we shall also believe, and not before. That is all there is in
>   religion."

*The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda, Volume 2, Jnana Yoga, Realisation.*

> "The proof, therefore, of the Vedas is just the same as the proof of
>   this table before me, pratyaksa, direct perception. This I see with
>   the senses, and the truths of spirituality we also see in a
>   superconscious state of the human soul."

*The Complete Works Of Swami Vivekananda, Volume 3, The Sages of India*

**Attitude towards Smritis and Puranas**

Smritis and Puranas are followed by traditional Vedantists.

> Such a God I have seen in my life, and his commands I live to follow.
>   **The Smritis and the Puranas are productions of men of limited
>   intelligence and are full of fallacies, errors, the feelings of class
>   and malice.** Only parts of them breathing broadness of spirit and love
>   are acceptable, **the rest are to be rejected.**

*The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda, Volume 6, Epistles – Second Series, CXXIV*

**Attitude towards Sankara’s Advaita Vedanta and Ramanuja’s Vishistadvaita Vedanta**

Traditional Vedantists follow either Sankara's Advaita or Ramanuja's or Madhva's or the Vedanta ofother famous Acaryas. Given below is what Ramakrishna says on this issue.

> MASTER: "Again, I cannot utter a word unless I come down at least two
>   steps from the plane of samadhi. Sankara's Non-dualistic explanation
>   of Vedanta is true, and so is the Qualified Non-dualistic
>   interpretation of Ramanuja."

*The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, With the Devotees in Calcutta, March 11, 1885*

**Is the universe unreal?**

Traditional Advaita Vedanta says that the world is unreal. I post below Sri Ramakrishna's teaching.

> Master (to M): ”Why should the universe be unreal? That is a
>   speculation of the  philosophers. After realizing God, one sees that
>   it is God Himself who has become the universe and all living beings.
>
> “The Divine Mother revealed to me in the Kali temple that it was She
>   who  had become everything. She showed me that everything was full of 
>   Consciousness. The Image was Consciouness, the altar was
>   Consciousness, the water-vessels were Consciousness, the door-sill was
>   Consciousness, the marble floor was Consciousness - all was
>   Consciousness.
>
> I found everything inside soaked, as it were, in Bliss
>   - the Bliss of Satchidananda. ..........
>
> “After realizing God, one sees all this aright - that it is He who has
>   become the universe, living
>   beings, and the twenty four cosmic principles. But what remains when
>   God completely effaces the ego can not be described in words. As
>   Ramprasad said in one of his songs, 'Then alone will you know whether
>   you are good or I am good!'
>
> A man sees one way through reasoning and
>   in an altogether different way when God Himself shows it to Him.

*The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, With the Devotees at Dakshineswar (II), December 16, 1883*

**Dr. Radhakrishnan**

He was very critical of Gaudapada’s theory of Ajatavada, a version of Advaita Vedanta. I give below an example of him attacking a version of Advaita Vedanta.

> The general idea, pervading Gaudapada’s work, that bondage and
>   liberation, the individual soul and the world, are all unreal, makes
>   the caustic critic observe that the theory which has nothing better to
>   say than that an unreal soul is trying to escape from an unreal
>   bondage in an unreal world to accomplish an unreal supreme good, may
>   itself be an unreality. It is one thing to say that the secret of
>   existence, how the unchangeable reality expresses itself in the
>   changing universe without forfeiting its nature, is a mystery, and
>   another to dismiss the whole changing universe as a mere mirage. If we
>   have to play the game of life, we cannot do so with the conviction
>   that the play is a show and all the prizes in it mere blanks. No
>   philosophy can consistently hold such a view and be at rest with
>   itself. The greatest condemnation of such a theory is that we are
>   obliged to occupy ourselves with objects, the existence and value of
>   which we are continually denying in theory. The fact of the world may
>   be mysterious and inexplicable. It only shows that there is something
>   else which includes and transcends the world; but it does not imply
>   that the world is a dream.

*Indian Philosophy, The Advaita Vedanta of Samkara, Gaudapada and Buddhism VIII by S. Radhakrishnan*

Comment: In first quote, where does Vivekananda says Vedas are not proof but *only* Pratyaksha? He says what Vedas say should be same as our Anubhava through Sadhana and realization. Also, there are other Advaitins who tried to reconcile Yoga, Samkhya and Vedanta. Even there are Advaita Acharyas and Swamis in India (especially in Telugu states) who reconcile various philosophies. I think these points can't be criteria to differentiate "Traditional" and "Neo".

Comment: Why are you quoting views of Swami Vivekananda and Sri Ramakrishna as those of neo-Vedanta? where did they proclaim themselves to be neo-vedantists? You need to first show that they are indeed "neo-vedantin".

Comment: I wrote that western Indologists consider Swami Vivekananda and Sri Ramakrishna as neo-Vedantins. The source is "Indra's Net' by Rajiv Malhotra. Some western Indologists claim, according to that book, that Hindusim was invented by Vivekananda around 1900.